# SourceTree: Your repository isn't properly configured

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, bitbucket-server

I just installed sourceTree and configured my BitBucket server on it. Everything's working fine, but every time I open a repository in SourceTree, I'm getting this warning.

[image: Error screenshot]

When I checked, the remote repository's URL matched what's configured in my sourceTree repository. Does anyone know what this means? Thanks!

Comment: I too am getting this on Mac. On Windows it's "SourceTree detected the following invalid Directory file references. Do you want to remove these invalid directories?" Both mention specific repositories and yet do not name them and neither choosing Repair nor Yes on Windows makes a lick of difference as they are asked on the next start. I'm going out on a short limb here and suggesting it's a bug introduced with the most recent version in the last few days - not uncommon for SourceTree unfortunately.

Comment: SourceTree 3.0 and this problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

The popup message explains the issue clearly. 
To resolve this issue, (1) click on Either Show Accounts from the popup or go to Preference -> Accounts. (2) Change the protocol to https from ssh or vice versa as per what is supported by your bitbucket account. Thanks